# image inside textblox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, border, stackpanel

hi i want show image inside textbox i can do this with this codes, but As you can see in the image, the images should be on the left side and the text on the right so how i can do this?
[see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkdme.png)

```
  <Border Background="#f0f4f7">
            <StackPanel Background="#f5f6fa" Margin="10,10,10,370">
                <TextBlock Text="1397-1398"/>
                <Border VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="#edf0f5" BorderThickness="5">
                    <StackPanel Background="#ffffff" Height="30">
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="#ffffff" Margin="5"
                    Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="E:\Aks\ICON\colorful-stickers-icons-set\png\32x32\trash.png" 
                   Height="18"/>
                            <Image Source="E:\Aks\ICON\colorful-stickers-icons-set\png\32x32\accept.png" 
                   Height="18"/>
                            <TextBlock Foreground="#7c7f84" Text="یکسری اطلاعات برای نمایش در اینجا"
                       Margin="3 0 0 0"/>
                        </StackPanel>

                    </StackPanel>
                </Border>
            </StackPanel>

        </Border>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a `Grid` with two columns will work:

```
<Border Background="#f0f4f7">
    <StackPanel Background="#f5f6fa" Margin="10,10,10,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock Text="1397-1398"/>
        <Border Background="#edf0f5" BorderThickness="5">
            <Grid Background="#ffffff" Height="30">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Background="#ffffff" Margin="5" Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="E:\Aks\ICON\colorful-stickers-icons-set\png\32x32\trash.png" 
                           Height="18"/>
                    <Image Source="E:\Aks\ICON\colorful-stickers-icons-set\png\32x32\accept.png" 
                           Height="18"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Foreground="#7c7f84" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Text="یکسری اطلاعات برای نمایش در اینجا"
                   Margin="3 0 0 0"/>
            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Also, using `VerticalAlignment=Center` on your border is unnecessary because it is contained within a `StackPanel`.

You may also want to take a look at the documentation for right-to-left layouts:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/bidirectional-features-in-wpf-overview